# How to determine power using standard error and effect size?

Tags: experiment-design, standard-error, statistical-power, ab-test

I was reading this [article](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/designing-experimentation-guardrails-ed6a976ec669) published from airbnb around gaurdrail metrics. In it, they discuss this power guardrail they derived but it's very unclear how they went about it. [image]

How are they determining Power given the effect (0.8)*t using no other information?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question in the body of the post very literally, it is indeed impossible to determine the power given the effect $0.8 * t$ without using other information.

I believe the blog post has made the following assumptions as well:

- The sample size in Airbnb is sufficiently large for experimenters to rely on CLT and run Student's/Welch's t-tests with a very large degrees of freedom, i.e. having the test statistic effectively normally distributed (common in digital experiments);
- Given they are discussing guardrail metrics, they are likely to be looking for potential harm only and hence using a one-tailed test, i.e. $H_1: \mu_B - \mu_A < 0$ (common in digital experiments);
- The null hypothesis is $H_0: \mu_B - \mu_A = 0$ (common in digital experiments - one can also use the composite variant, see e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/justification-of-one-tailed-hypothesis-testing));
- The significance level (or size), given we are using t-tests, is $\alpha=10\%$. (stated in blog post); and
- The standard error "if an experiment just meets the power guardrail" is $0.8 * t$. (stated in blog post).

Under these assumptions, The [power of a one-tailed (less than) t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test#Example) with a very large degrees of freedom for a specific effect size $\theta$ is:

$$B(\theta) \approx \Phi\left(z_{\alpha} - \frac{\theta}{\textrm{std. error}}\right), $$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal CDF, and $z_{1-\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$ quantile of a standard normal. Note the linked wiki page gives the power calculations for a "greater than" one-tailed test, and we have to flip the signs here as we have a "less than" one-tailed test.

Given we know $z_{\alpha} \approx -1.28 $ for $\alpha=0.1$, this means:

- If $\theta = -t$,
  $$\begin{align}
      B(\theta) & \approx \Phi\left( -1.28 - \frac{-t} 
  {0.8*t}\right) \\ 
      & = \Phi(-1.28+1.25) \\
      & \approx \Phi(0) = 0.5 
      \end{align}$$
- If $\theta = -2t$,
  $$\begin{align}
      B(\theta) & \approx \Phi\left( -1.28 - \frac{-2t} 
  {0.8*t}\right) \\ 
      & = \Phi(-1.28+2.5) \\
      & \approx \Phi(1.28) \approx 0.9 
      \end{align}$$

I can only assume the multiplier $0.8$ is chosen as $1/z_{1-\alpha} = 0.78030...$ may be harder to remember by heart. Having that said, all of the above are meant as rules of thumb and thus we should expect approximations here and there.

Comment: really appreciate the thoughtfulness and insight here! Was racking my brain trying to logically get here :)